# Choropleth doesn't display in Altair

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I'm trying to create a choropleth from some data but something isn't working.

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

dat = {
    'country': [
        'France', 'Belgium', 'United Kingdom', 'Iraq', 'Turkey (including Gallipoli)',
        'Iran', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'India', 'Egypt', 'Greece', 'Malta',
        'Ireland, Republic of', 'Pakistan', 'Azerbaijan', 'Switzerland', 'Poland',
        'Israel and Palestine (including Gaza)', 'Tanzania', 'Gibraltar', 'Kenya', 'Mozambique', 'Netherlands'
    ],
    'count': [
        7507, 2609, 686, 577, 414, 95, 93, 74, 72, 35, 24, 21,
        20, 19, 14, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

# Use altair's built-in world map data
world = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')

# Create the choropleth map
choropleth = alt.Chart(world).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
).encode(
    color=alt.Color('count:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='viridis')),
    tooltip=['country:N', 'count:Q']
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(df, 'country', ['count'])
).properties(
    title='Number of Deaths by Country'
).project('equirectangular')

choropleth
```

The result is:

[image]

Where's the map?

Answer (score 1):

You're lookup is wrong, you need to look-up on [ID codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_numeric) instead of country name.

The code below does this by appending a column for ISO 3166 codes and those are used to lookup on the map:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data
# !pip install iso3166
from iso3166 import countries

dat = {
    'country': [
        'France', 'Belgium', 'United Kingdom', 'Iraq', 'Turkey (including Gallipoli)',
        'Iran', 'Germany', 'Italy', 'India', 'Egypt', 'Greece', 'Malta',
        'Ireland, Republic of', 'Pakistan', 'Azerbaijan', 'Switzerland', 'Poland',
        'Israel and Palestine (including Gaza)', 'Tanzania', 'Gibraltar', 'Kenya', 'Mozambique', 'Netherlands'
    ],
    'count': [
        7507, 2609, 686, 577, 414, 95, 93, 74, 72, 35, 24, 21,
        20, 19, 14, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(dat)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(countries)[['name', 'numeric']]
df2.rename(columns={'name': 'country', 'numeric': 'id'}, inplace=True)
df = df.merge(df2,on = 'country')

# Use altair's built-in world map data
world = alt.topo_feature(data.world_110m.url, 'countries')

# # Create the choropleth map
choropleth = alt.Chart(world).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
).encode(
    color=alt.Color('count:Q', scale=alt.Scale(scheme='viridis')),
    tooltip=['country:N', 'count:Q']
).transform_lookup(
    lookup='id',
    from_=alt.LookupData(df, 'id', ['country','count'])
).properties(
    title='Number of Deaths by Country'
).project('equirectangular')
choropleth
```

Output:

[image]